# Simple fields Wordpress

Tags: content-management-system, wordpress

I am trying to use simple fields in my theme but I cant put it in the theme, I tried everything.

I have made this in my new post to show up:

http://pokit.org/get/?1cbbe77cc829c2c875e11d9a58ac5866.jpg

How can I make simple fields generate this in my single.php :

```
<li>
simple fileds content (value)
</li>
```

and when i go add+ go generate another

```
<li>
simple fileds content (value)
</li>
```

Thanks !

Comment: What is "simple fields"?

Comment: I have figured out how to loop one filed, like this :

`<?php
$repeatable_field_values = simple_fields_values("text_page");
foreach ($repeatable_field_values as $values) { 

echo " <li>
<div class='small-12 large-6 columns text'>
$values>
 </li>";
}
?>`
but now i need to figure out how to put a image field also ?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation is always a good idea.

See http://simple-fields.com/documentation/getting-started/tutorial-part-2/ for details.

I think you will need the code from Method 3.